# R automatically writing charts/graphs to files

Tags: r, charts, plot, automation

In R, I have a script which generates 2134 graphical plots. In the R environment a graphics windows pops open and flips through all 2134 graphical plots while the script is running. Specifically, these are ACF plots and I would like to be able to write all of these graphical plots to a file.

In the past if I only had a chart or two, I would just right click, select copy as bitmap and save as a word document. The key is automating this process, as it is not feasible for a human to righ click and copy/paste for 2134 plots.

1. How do I write these graphical plots to a file?
2. What is the best file format to do this?
3. Is there already a package that will do this for me?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need a package.  Check out the `pdf`, `png`, `jpeg`, `bmp` functions.  There isn't necessarily a 'best' file format - it depends on what you want.

Comment: png = web/MS Word doc, pdf = latex, svg = when allowed, jpeg/bmp = when you care more about compression (I don't know much about these alter 2 and rarely use them) [my guidelines for when to use what graphic type]

Comment: As a quick pseduo-example if you want all plots in one file, one page each: `pdf(~/"myplots.pdf" , onefile = TRUE ) ; yourplottingcodegoeshere ; dev.off()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Dason already answered, but you could try

```
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(1:10,1:10)
hist(rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
```

With this all your graph will be sent to a .pdf file.

If you use some image format you can print a picture at time. You can adjust many parameters of your image (use par() to see all), including the size. For me pdf is nice, because of its resolution (I don't know why other images don't have the same resolution).

Another thing that you can do is to use this trick in an image function

```
png("%003d.png", h=768, w=1024)
plot(1:10,1:10)
hist(rnorm(1000))
dev.off()
```

This will help you if you need all plot individually.

Hope this Helps.

Cheers

Comment: Wow, I did not know you could specify output files like that. Amazing!